MySQL SQL EXISTS clause fails as workaround for LIMIT usage restrictions
I was testing the query below thinking it would get me around the "can't use LIMIT in subqueries" restriction. The query runs but the average is simply the average of all the records WHERE MScores.MemberId=1193 AND MScores.Div="FSO"
It seems to completely ignore the EXISTS clause.
The query should return the rolling average of the 5 (or less) most recent scores for a specific member in a specific division.
Any ideas why the EXISTS clause fails to affect the results?
  SELECT MScores.MemberId, MScores.`Div`, AVG(MScores.Final) AS AvgOfFinal
    FROM qryMatchScores MScores
    WHERE MScores.MemberId=1193 AND MScores.`Div`="FSO" AND 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT MatchDate 
        FROM qryMatchScores MDates
        WHERE 
            MDates.MemberId = MScores.MemberId AND 
            MDates.`Div` = MScores.`Div` AND
            MDates.MatchDate = MScores.MatchDate
        ORDER BY MatchDate DESC
        LIMIT 5
    );

Update====================================================
I appreciated all the responses but after finding a solution realized that all but one response came from folks with little to no MySQL (MariaDb specific) experience.
Thanks to @joel-coehoorn (marked as answer) for his solution which confirmed what I eventually came up with... they're almost exactly the same!
SELECT MemberId, `Div`, AVG(Final) AS RollingAVG 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        MemberId, 
        `Div`, 
        Final, 
        MatchDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberId, `Div` ORDER BY MatchDate DESC) AS row_num
    FROM qryMatchScores
    ORDER BY MemberId, `Div`
    ) AS MScores
WHERE row_num <= 5
GROUP BY MemberId, `Div`;

...and thanks to all who downvoted the question. You really know how to encourage others!

Can you create a reproducer? https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT can be used.

Your exist looks suuspios wrong make a full [mre]

Start with enabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

BTW. the EXISTS is true if at least one row is returned from the subquery.

What is your actual goal here?

The query should not have run.  How can you aggregate without a GROUP BY?

This test version doesn't need a group by. The MemberId and Div fields are specified. Once I find a working solution, I'd remove the
WHERE MScores.MemberId=1193 AND MScores.Div="FSO"
and add the GROUP BY clause.

FYI... SQL aggregates do not require a GROUP BY clause. If omitted the aggregate is returned for the entire data set.

Sample data and expected results are essential. By the way, your query makes no sense, because LIMIT (without an offset) and ORDER BY and SELECT columns are not used in the EXISTS check, it's only whether there are any rows in the subquery. You probably want an AVG OVER window function, but really hard to say without more info.

@MarkP, only when MySQL run with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled. Not recommended.

I think what you really need to do is JOIN with the subquery that uses ORDER BY and LIMIT, not use EXISTS.

@jarlh They're only selecting a single MemberId and Div, so grouping by those columns won't change the aggregation.

It would help if you tried row_number()
Select MemberId, `Div`, AVG(Final) as AvgOfFinal
from 
(
    Select 
        MScores.MemberId, 
        MScores.`Div`, 
        MScores.Final,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MScores.MemberId, MScores.`Div` order by MScores.MatchDate desc) AS rn
    from qryMatchScores MScores
    where MScores.MemberId = 1193 AND MScores.`Div` = 'FSO'
) as RankedScores
where rn <= 5
group by 1,2;


Without some sample data and coresponding expected result, It's hard to tell what you want to do. Another thing not completely explained is your statement:

The query should return the rolling average of the 5 (or less) most recent
scores for a specific member in a specific division

As far as I understood it - this is something that could be solved using Avg() Over() analytic function with windowing clause and Row_Number() to handle ordering (and scope if needed) ...
Create Table 
  MatchScores ( MemberId Int, Division Text, Final Int, MatchDate Date );
--
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Insert Into MatchScores ( MemberId, Division, Final, MatchDate ) 
  VALUES
    ( 101, 'FSO', 100, '2024-07-01' ),
    ( 101, 'FSO', 110, '2024-07-02' ),
    ( 101, 'FSO', 120, '2024-07-03' ),
    ( 101, 'FSO', 120, '2024-07-04' ),
    ( 101, 'FSO', 100, '2024-07-05' ),
    ( 101, 'FSO', 130, '2024-07-06' ),
    ( 101, 'FSO', 100, '2024-07-07' ),
      --
    ( 201, 'FSO', 10, '2024-07-01' ),
    ( 201, 'FSO', 16, '2024-07-02' ),
    ( 201, 'FSO', 10, '2024-07-03' ),
    ( 201, 'FSO', 14, '2024-07-04' ),
    ( 201, 'FSO', 12, '2024-07-05' ),
      --
    ( 301, 'FSO', 1, '2024-07-01' ),
    ( 301, 'FSO', 3, '2024-07-02' );

... SQL getting rolling (running) average in both ways ordered by date and an average of all rows fetched ...
SELECT    ms.MemberId, ms.Division, ms.Final, ms.MatchDate,  
          Avg(Final) Over( Partition By ms.MemberId 
                           Order By ms.RN 
                           Rows Between 4 Preceding And Current Row) as rolling_avg,
         Avg(Final) Over( Partition By ms.MemberId ) as avg, 
         Avg(Final) Over( Partition By ms.MemberId 
                           Order By ms.RN Desc
                           Rows Between 4 Preceding And Current Row) as reversed_rolling_avg,
        ms.RN
FROM    ( Select    MemberId, Division, Final, MatchDate, 
                    Row_Number() 
                         Over( Partition By MemberId Order By MatchDate Desc) as RN
          From      MatchScores
        ) ms
ORDER BY  ms.MemberId, ms.RN;

/*      R e s u l t : 
MemberId  Division       Final  MatchDate   rolling_avg         avg  reversed_rolling_avg  RN
--------  --------  ----------  ----------  -----------  ----------  --------------------  --
     101  FSO              100  2024-07-07     100.0000    111.4286              114.0000   1
     101  FSO              130  2024-07-06     115.0000    111.4286              116.0000   2
     101  FSO              100  2024-07-05     110.0000    111.4286              110.0000   3
     101  FSO              120  2024-07-04     112.5000    111.4286              112.5000   4
     101  FSO              120  2024-07-03     114.0000    111.4286              110.0000   5
     101  FSO              110  2024-07-02     116.0000    111.4286              105.0000   6
     101  FSO              100  2024-07-01     110.0000    111.4286              100.0000   7
     201  FSO               12  2024-07-05      12.0000     12.4000               12.4000   1
     201  FSO               14  2024-07-04      13.0000     12.4000               12.5000   2
     201  FSO               10  2024-07-03      12.0000     12.4000               12.0000   3
     201  FSO               16  2024-07-02      13.0000     12.4000               13.0000   4
     201  FSO               10  2024-07-01      12.4000     12.4000               10.0000   5
     301  FSO                3  2024-07-02       3.0000      2.0000                2.0000   1
     301  FSO                1  2024-07-01       2.0000      2.0000                1.0000   2    */

... if you want to filter (limit) the whole thing to just 5 latest rows per id - just add WHERE clause to outer query ...
SELECT    ms.MemberId, ms.Division, ms.Final, ms.MatchDate,  
          Avg(Final) Over( Partition By ms.MemberId 
                           Order By ms.RN 
                           Rows Between 4 Preceding And Current Row) as rolling_avg,
         Avg(Final) Over( Partition By ms.MemberId ) as avg, 
         Avg(Final) Over( Partition By ms.MemberId 
                           Order By ms.RN Desc
                           Rows Between 4 Preceding And Current Row) as reversed_rolling_avg,
       
        ms.RN
FROM    ( Select    MemberId, Division, Final, MatchDate, 
                    Row_Number() 
                         Over( Partition By MemberId Order By MatchDate Desc) as RN
          From      MatchScores
        ) ms
WHERE     ms.RN <= 5         -- filtering to just 5 latest rows per id
ORDER BY  ms.MemberId, ms.RN;

/*      R e s u l t :
MemberId  Division       Final  MatchDate   rolling_avg         avg  reversed_rolling_avg  RN
--------  --------  ----------  ----------  -----------  ----------  --------------------  --
     101  FSO              100  2024-07-07     100.0000    114.0000              114.0000   1
     101  FSO              130  2024-07-06     115.0000    114.0000              117.5000   2
     101  FSO              100  2024-07-05     110.0000    114.0000              113.3333   3
     101  FSO              120  2024-07-04     112.5000    114.0000              120.0000   4
     101  FSO              120  2024-07-03     114.0000    114.0000              120.0000   5
     201  FSO               12  2024-07-05      12.0000     12.4000               12.4000   1
     201  FSO               14  2024-07-04      13.0000     12.4000               12.5000   2
     201  FSO               10  2024-07-03      12.0000     12.4000               12.0000   3
     201  FSO               16  2024-07-02      13.0000     12.4000               13.0000   4
     201  FSO               10  2024-07-01      12.4000     12.4000               10.0000   5
     301  FSO                3  2024-07-02       3.0000      2.0000                2.0000   1
     301  FSO                1  2024-07-01       2.0000      2.0000                1.0000   2    */

See the fiddle here.
NOTE:
Depending on your actual data, you'll need to add Division column to Partition By clause (with MemberId) of analytic functions (in case that 1 MemberId could be with 2 Divisions) OR to do the Division filtering in WHERE clause (if 1 MemberId is always with 1 Division) ...

ROW_NUMBER() and windowing functions are definitely the way to go here... no LIMIT needed or wanted, which is non-standard sql anyway.

You are trying to do two separate and incompatible things in your exists subquery: select the most recent 5 dates, and filter by the date of the outer row.  You can't have both.  The closest thing to your approach I can come up with is:
select AVG(MScores.Final) AvgOfFinal
from qryMatchScores MScores
where MScores.MemberId=1193 and MScores.`Div`="FSO" and 5 > (
  select count(distinct MDates.MatchDate)
  from qryMatchScores MDates
  where (MScores.MemberId,MScores.`Div`)=(MDates.MemberId,MDates.`Div`) and
      MDates.MatchDate > MScores.MatchDate
)

